# Show hide Textbox based on radio button list value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to hide `txtsearch` when the `RadioButtonListvalue = OrderDate` to hide `txtsearch` and show `txtsearch` if any other value is selected

I tried the code below it didn't work

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (lblfield.SelectedValue == "OrderDate")
    {
         txtsearch.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
         txtsearch.Visible = true;
    }
}

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="lblfield" runat="server" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="10" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" Width="460px">
       <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Cust_Name">Customer</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="OrderDate">Order Date</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="TotalAmount">Total Amount</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="InvoiceStatus">Invoice Status</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>


 <asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: On what event will the RadioButtonList be set to "OrderDate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `if (!IsPostBack)`. Just remove `if (!IsPostBack)` and then code works fine.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     if (lblfield.SelectedValue == "OrderDate")
     {
          txtsearch.Visible = false;
     }

     else
     {
          txtsearch.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

Or just in one line:

```
txtsearch.Visible = lblfield.SelectedValue == "OrderDate" ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create an Event for your `RadioButton` `SelectedIndexChanged`. Then you can call it in page load and also you have more control on it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblfield_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
}

protected void lblfield_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lblfield.SelectedValue == "OrderDate")
        txtsearch.Visible = false;
    else
        txtsearch.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to do this using JQuery without server call because that is too costly.